# RecyclerView cambiar texto OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, interfaz-gráfica, android-recyclerview

Tengo un RecyclerView que muestra todos los productos disponibles para realizar una orden, a este le agregue un botón el cual al momento de darle click cambia su texto para mostrar que se encuentre seleccionado y envia los datos de dicho producto a un arrayList que muestra todos los productos seleccionados dentro de otro Activity.

El problema se produce al momento de seleccionar varios elementos y cambiar el texto a seleccionado. Si selecciono un par de productos se comporta bien pero al momento de seleccionar varios, cambia todos los textos a seleccionados como se ve en el GIF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta acción la efectuó dentro del adaptador en el OnBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  AdaptadorProductos.AdaptadorRvHolder holder, int position) {
    final Productos currentItem = productos.get(position);
    holder.txtProducto.setText(currentItem.getNombreProducto());
    holder.txtCodigoERP.setText("Codigo : "+currentItem.getCodigoERP());
    holder.txtUnidadMedida.setText(currentItem.getUnidadMedida());
    holder.btnAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            codigoERP = currentItem.getCodigoERP();
            nombreProducto = currentItem.getNombreProducto();
            unidadMedida =  currentItem.getUnidadMedida();
            ((ActualizaProductoSeleccionado) ApplicationMain.getMyContext()).addProductos(nombreProducto,codigoERP,unidadMedida);
            holder.btnAgregar.setText("OK");
        }
    });
}
```

Espero se entienda la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: No estaría viendo cuál es el error en concreto o no lo estaría entendiendo muy bien...

Comment: el problema se ve en el Gift, al momento de seleccionar varios productos, me cambia el estado de todo el RecyClerView(mas de 1000 registros), cambia de estado "+" a "O".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade en tu adaptador si aun no lo tienes:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

> La implementación predeterminada de getItemViewType devuelve 0,
> asumiendo un solo tipo de vista para el adaptador. Anularlo le permite
> al adaptador saber que hay varios tipos de vista y ajustar en
> consecuencia.

Comment: Me sirvió,  justamente eso era lo que necesitaba. Pero no lo termino de entender ya que no tengo múltiples tipos de vistas(según yo)

Comment: Efectivamente solo tienes un tipo de vista, pero más que nada getItemViewType te sirve si usas más de una, en tu caso getItemId es ell importante ya que retorna el id asociado con la posición especificada en la lista. [Referencia](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItemId(int))